# Enable button when select option in PHP using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried some code from other topics to resolve my problem here but I still don't manage to get what I want..

I need a button to goes enable when the user select one of the item in a select option and goes to disable when the users re-select the default select..

```
    <script text="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#select_resa').change(function(){
        var val = $('#select_resa').val();
        alert(val);

        if (val == '') {
            $('#supprimer_resa_button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }else{
            $('#supprimer_resa_button').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
});
</script>

<form method="post" action="modif_resa.php?" id="modif_resa">
    <h2>Modifier/Supprimer un reservation</h2>
    <?php if(isset($erreur)) echo '<p style="font-style:italic;font-size:0.8em;text-align:center;color:red;margin-bottom:5px;">'.$erreur.'</p>'; ?>



    <label for="salle"><strong>Choisissez une reservation</strong></label>

    <select id="select_resa" name="select_resa">
        <option value="" id="select" name="select">--Selectionnez--</option>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="2">salut</option>
        <?php
        if(!empty($liste_reservations)){
            for($i=0;$i<count($liste_reservations);$i++){
                echo '<option "title="'.$liste_reservations[$i]['RS_NOM'].'" value="'.$liste_reservations[$i]['RS_NOM'].'" '.(isset($SALLE) && $SALLE==$liste_reservations[$i]['RS_ID']?'selected="selected"':'').'>'.$liste_reservations[$i]['RS_NOM'].'</option>';
            }
        }
        ?>
   </select>

   <br/><br/>


    <label for="s_date"> Modifier la date de fin</label>
    <input type="text" value="<?php if(isset($RS_DATE)) echo $RS_DATE;?>" name="s_date" id="s_date"  maxlength="10" size="10"/>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);"   onclick="javascript:return CalendarDate('s_date');"><img src="/Libs/calendar/calendar_small.png" alt="Calendrier" style="vertical-align:middle; border:0;" title="Calendrier" /></a>
    <br/><br/> 

    <span class="valider">
    <input type="submit" name="valider" value="<?php echo TXT_VALIDER; ?>" />

    </span>

        <br/><br/>


    <div style="text-align:center; margin-top: 50px;">
    <input id="supprimer_resa_button" disabled="disabled" type="submit" name="supprimer_resa_button" style="font-size: 15px; width: auto; height:auto; font-weight:bold;" value="<?php echo TXT_SUPPRIMER_RESA; ?>" />
    </div>

</form>
```

My Submit button is enable in any case here...
Where am I wrong ?

Comment: Nothing to do with php at all, this is Javascript / jQuery.

Comment: Still nothing to do with php in regards of enabling / disabling a button upon value change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please check this:**

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<script text="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#select_resa').change(function(){
        var val = $('#select_resa').val();

        if (val == '') {
            $('#supprimer_resa_button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }else{
            $('#supprimer_resa_button').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
});



</script>

<form method="post" action="modif_resa.php?" id="modif_resa">
    <h2>Modifier/Supprimer un reservation</h2>
    <?php if(isset($erreur)) echo '<p style="font-style:italic;font-size:0.8em;text-align:center;color:red;margin-bottom:5px;">'.$erreur.'</p>'; ?>



    <label for="salle"><strong>Choisissez une reservation</strong></label>

    <select id="select_resa" name="select_resa">
        <option value="" id="select" name="select">--Selectionnez--</option>
        <option value="1">abc</option>
        <option value="2">def</option>
        <option value="3">ghi</option>
        <?php
        if(!empty($liste_reservations)){
            for($i=0;$i<count($liste_reservations);$i++){
                echo '<option "title="'.$liste_reservations[$i]['RS_NOM'].'" value="'.$liste_reservations[$i]['RS_ID'].'" '.(isset($SALLE) && $SALLE==$liste_reservations[$i]['RS_ID']?'selected="selected"':'').'>'.$liste_reservations[$i]['RS_NOM'].'</option>';
            }
        }
        ?>
   </select>

   <br/><br/>


    <label for="s_date"> Modifier la date de fin</label>
    <input type="text" value="<?php if(isset($RS_DATE)) echo $RS_DATE;?>" name="s_date" id="s_date"  maxlength="10" size="10"/>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);"   onclick="javascript:return CalendarDate('s_date');"><img src="/Libs/calendar/calendar_small.png" alt="Calendrier" style="vertical-align:middle; border:0;" title="Calendrier" /></a>
    <br/><br/>

    <span class="valider">
    <input type="submit" name="valider" value="<?php echo TXT_VALIDER; ?>" />

    </span>

        <br/><br/>


    <div style="text-align:center; margin-top: 50px;">
    <input id="supprimer_resa_button" disabled="disabled" type="submit" name="supprimer_resa_button" style="font-size: 15px; width: auto; height:auto; font-weight:bold;" value="<?php echo TXT_SUPPRIMER_RESA; ?>" />
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Why should OP *check this*? Please, provide detailed explanation on how your answer is a solution, for it to be useful to future users who'd visit this question.

Comment: sure. will be take care

Comment: it still disabled when I click on one of my item, even if I click on def for example

Comment: Maybe i'm wrong in how to put javascript outside my form ? Can you check it please.. I updated my code, I'll check your updated code thank you

Comment: did you insert jQuerymin.js

Comment: No.. I dont kow how to put it.. in my index2.php right ?
Sorry I'm pretty new in this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91102/discussion-between-ishan-shah-and-nemka).

Comment: It works perfectly I just looked your updated code ! Thank you mister

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use:

```
$('#supprimer_resa_button').removeAttr('disabled');
```

instead of

```
$('#supprimer_resa_button').attr('disabled', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

In recent jQuery api, you must use `prop` on boolean html attributes :

```
$('#supprimer_resa_button').prop('disabled', false)
```

Or

```
$('#supprimer_resa_button').prop('disabled', true)
```

`attr` is only with html attributes which can contain a value.

In your case, you can also do a little shorter :

```
function updateFormEnabled() {
    $('#supprimer_resa_button').prop('disabled', verifyAdSettings());
}
```

Comment: thank for answers ! 
Do i need to put the attribute disabled="disabled" on the button before ? or I let as the code above ?

Comment: If the button is disabled by default, you have to add it. Use `disabled="disabled"` if you are in xhtml. `disabled` only if you are in html